# Reclaim free space of container disk after Bootcamp error

Tags: macos, disk-utility, bootcamp, partition

My Mac has 1 physical SSD disk of 512 GB.

After Bootcamp going wrong, I now have 2 "physical" disks listed. One disk of 28 GB, which space I want to merge back to the main disk ("Macintosh SSD" now shown with size 499,9 GB):

[image]

Main disk "Macintosh SSD":

[image]

This is the `diskutil list` output:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *28.0 GB    disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
                    (free space)                         27.7 GB    -

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk2⁩         499.9 GB   disk1s2

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +499.9 GB   disk2
                                 Physical Store disk1s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh SSD - Gege...⁩ 203.0 GB   disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 270.2 MB   disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                1.1 GB     disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh SSD⁩           15.4 GB    disk2s4
   5:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 15.4 GB    disk2s4s1
   6:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      3.2 GB     disk2s5
```

NB: I have a backup of all files, so if the easiest solution would be to do a total re-install, then that would also be fine.

NB: It's not a Fusion drive, although that small 28GB drive would look like it. The Mac has 1 512 GB SSD drive.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can I assume you have a Time Machine backup, which you can used to restore macOS? I think you may to need to recreate a Fusion drive, which I believe will erase everything on your internal drives.  Afterwards, you would need to restore from a backup, such as would be provided by Time Machine.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I've updated my question. It's not a Fusion Drive. I would be ok to delete everything and start over from zero. I just don't know to reclaim that 28 GB drive which got added after Bootcamp stopped in the middle of the process.

Comment: I did not state that you have a Fusion Drive. I stated you **need to recreate a Fusion drive**.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of the question [Problem with internal SSD partitions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/446673/problem-with-internal-ssd-partitions).

Comment: @DavidAnderson You're right. I apparently have a FD. This fixed it, thanks. If you enter it as an answer then I can marked it on your name.

Comment: Marc: You can up vote [my answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/446673/problem-with-internal-ssd-partitions/446682#446682) to the other question.